# How to make an img tag valid according to w3c with str_replace or some other php function?

Tags: php, html, regex, w3c-validation

Lets say we have an image tag but is not w3c valid beacause in the end is missing "/>" :

```
<img src="myfile.png" alt="MyiMage" title="MyImage" border="0" >
```

Then how we can replace this with str_replace par example or an other php function so that we can make this image valid like :

```
<img src="myfile.png" alt="MyiMage" title="MyImage" border="0" />
```

Seems again that here we need some regular expression right(?) in order to mach somehow the "/>" or is some other ways we can implement this too ?

Comment: How is the image tag stored? Are you generating it all through PHP, or is it pulled from a database or text file, and you want to amend it as it's output?

Comment: Hi i simply do a SELECT before from Mysql and then am echoing it as a variable. So ?

Comment: It is valid in HTML, it just isn't in XHTML. The benefits of XHTML are very rare, experienced only by developers, and not experienced by most of them. Use HTML instead of XHTML.

Comment: So you select the peices, or the select returns full `text` that you output?

Comment: Quentin, i want to have it in XHTML valid NOT in HTML and this cause my website is in XHTML. so how..?

Comment: Jon i do a simple SELECT and then i have the image data in a variable.. while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){$var1 = $rows['field']; echo $var1;}

Comment: Where is the code that generates the img tag in the first place? Just alter that.

Comment: Anyway.. my question is about how we can make an img tag XHTML valid hm ?

Comment: Show the code, please.

Comment: Digital Chris my code is so simple and here is it : http://pastebin.com/i3gtbYLW

Comment: I can't load that link where I am. Here is my point: SOME code generates the `<IMG` tag. Alter that code to include a `/>` rather than trying to go back and regex it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find :  `<img\s[^>]*\K(?<!/)>`
replace:  `/>`

**PHP Old test case** using preg_replace() -

```
 $xhtml = '<img src="myfile.png" alt="MyiMage" title="MyImage" border="0" >';
 $str = preg_replace( '~<img\s[^>]*\K(?<!/)>~', "/>", $xhtml );

 print $xhtml. "\n";
 print $str;
```

**Edit**  - Due to a downvote, I will amend the regex.
This is for the purist out there that think html/xhtml/xml should be parsed with regex.
*To the OP - The original regex is easier to understand (and probably better!).*

**PHP New test case**

```
 $xhtml = '<img src="myfile.png" alt="MyiMage" title="MyImage" border="0" >';
 $str = preg_replace( '~(?s)<img(?=\s|>)(?>(?:".*?"|\'.*?\'|[^>]*?)+\K>)(?<!/>)~', "/>", $xhtml );

 print $xhtml. "\n";
 print $str;
```

Output >>

```
 <img src="myfile.png" alt="MyiMage" title="MyImage" border="0" >
 <img src="myfile.png" alt="MyiMage" title="MyImage" border="0" />
```

**New Regex explained**

```
 # '~(?s)<img(?=\s|>)(?>(?:".*?"|\'.*?\'|[^>]*?)+\K>)(?<!/>)~'

 (?s)                 # Dot-All modifier
 <img                 # 'img' tag
 (?= \s | > )         # Assert followed by a whitespace or closing tag
 (?>                  # Atomic magic - 
      (?:                  # Do this many times
           " .*? "              # Anything in double quotes
        |  ' .*? '              # Anything in single quotes
        |  [^>]*?               # Least amount of non '>' chars as possible
      )+
      \K                   # \K, don't include up to here in the match output
      >                    # Finally, the closing '>', the only character in match output
 )
 (?<! /> )            # Assert that tag was not closed
```

Comment: sln.. am not familiar with regular expressions please can you explain me how to apply what youve just wrote ?

Comment: @anny32 - Added info.

Comment: sln Thanks a lot works !!!

Comment: The center cannot hold, it is too late.

Comment: -1 This answer is wrong, ">" must not be escaped in attribute values in XML, therefore, the end of the IMG element can not be found if an attribute value contains ">".

Comment: @MadaraUchiha The pony! he comes! All is lost! **LOST!**

Comment: @hakre - It seems you are right (sort of). I changed the regex to handle (not validate) html/xhtml/xml. To save your eyes, I posted a simple rendition of a gigantic regex I could have used.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha - Who is that `pony!` you keep referring to?

Comment: @sln I think they are referring to this [rant](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454)

Answer (score 2):

Let's say we have this string:

```
$my_img = '<img src="myfile.png" alt="MyiMage" title="MyImage" border="0" >';
```

To make it a self-closing tag, you can indeed use `str_replace`:

```
$my_img = str_replace('>', '/>', $my_img);
```

---

## Update

This should do the trick:

```
$str = '<img src="myfile.png" alt="MyiMage" title="MyImage" border="0" >';
$str_2 = preg_replace('/(<img .+)( >)/', '${1} />', $str);
```

We take `$str` and put it in the `preg_replace` where we look for a pattern that matches only `img` tags and change the *>* to */>*.

Comment: And what if par example our image has a title=">" in this case it works again correct ?

Comment: Your answer is not correct in case we have an a href including the img tag then a href tag end is having trouble, is becoming like ..<a href=""></a/> instead of </a>

Comment: This is why you should provide a more detailed question then. Partial question = incomplete/incorrect answer. It's easy to solve this with `preg_replace`, but I can't exactly understand what needs to be fixed, please elaborate.

Comment: Ok my english aint not good.. :( i know this but am trying as best i can to define my questions.. hm if you understood better what i mean now if you know please try to help me cause the answer that you gave me is not working when other tags such as <a href> par example exists

Answer (score 0):

as far as I can tell you have `html` inside your database. There are 2 options for solving your dilemma

- the long *lasting bug-squasher* would be to make an update on every row where this happens, I would use `preg_replace` for such a task. The validating all new content getting inserted
- the *garbage solution that works and is easy to implement* would be to alter the output, again with `preg_replace`.

As you can see, the obvious choice is to use regular expresions. The best choice is to stop putting html inside your database that way and/or updating all tuples to conform to your new rules

I believe user `sln` gave you a pretty good **regExp**